# Not Equals (!=) not operating as expected

Tags: sql, oracle

first off do you see a problem with this code;

```
 SELECT num,
        surname, 
        firstname,
        ward 
   FROM doctor, ward WHERE num != consultant;

  NUM SURNAME    FIRSTNAME  W
---------- ---------- ---------- -
  203 Black      Peter      A
  574 Bisi       Mavis      B
  461 Boyne      Steve      B
  530 Clark      Nicola     C
  405 Mizzi      Nicola     A
  501 Mount      Mavis      A
  203 Black      Peter      A

  C NAME       CONSULTANT
  - ---------- ----------
  A Surgical          203
  B Paediatric        574
  C Medical           530
```

I Expected the output to be something like;

```
 461 Boyne      Steve      B
 405 Mizzi      Nicola     A
 501 Mount      Mavis      A
```

Thinking the result that aren't equal will be displayed, However when I execute the command the result is this;

```
       NUM SURNAME    FIRSTNAME  W
---------- ---------- ---------- -
       574 Bisi       Mavis      B
       461 Boyne      Steve      B
       530 Clark      Nicola     C
       405 Mizzi      Nicola     A
       501 Mount      Mavis      A
       203 Black      Peter      A
       461 Boyne      Steve      B
       530 Clark      Nicola     C
       405 Mizzi      Nicola     A
       501 Mount      Mavis      A
       203 Black      Peter      A

       NUM SURNAME    FIRSTNAME  W
---------- ---------- ---------- -
       203 Black      Peter      A
       574 Bisi       Mavis      B
       461 Boyne      Steve      B
       405 Mizzi      Nicola     A
       501 Mount      Mavis      A
       203 Black      Peter      A
```

I am rather fresh to Oracle so It might be a noob mistake but any assistance would be great.

Comment: The actual output for the query seems to be correct, you might be better off asking how you can achieve what you want (hint: look at `NOT EXISTS`, `NOT IN` or a `LEFT JOIN` + a condition on a righthand column being `NULL`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Here is the SQLFiddel Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cef82/2)**

I think the best way to achive your output is using `not exsits`.

**Below is the query which you can try**

```
 SELECT *
   FROM doctor
  WHERE not exists (select 1 
                      from ward 
                     where num = consultant)
```

Comment: Great thanks Roms after looking up Not Exists I get it now you are comparing doctor with ward and it returns the numbers that don't exist in the table consultant but do in num. =) I have the text book in front of me but It didn't make sense when I read it :/... I dunno thanks anyway Thumbs for you :D

Comment: Thanks, have great time... :)

Answer (score 5):

You need a left outer join:

```
 SELECT num,surname, firstname,ward
 FROM doctor left outer join
      ward
      on num = consultant
 WHERE num is null;
```

The problem with your query is that you are doing a Cartesian product (all combinations) between `doctor` and `ward`.  Then you are choosing the rows where the two values are different.

An alternative way to write the above may be clearer:

```
select d.*
from doctor d
where d.num not in (select consultant from ward);
```

Answer (score 2):

your query is creating a cartesian product 
whereas the correct query should be

```
SELECT num,surname, firstname,ward FROM doctor join ward on (c = w) WHERE num != consultant;
```

Answer (score 1):

add an " and w = C " to your statement to build the join.

or use

```
SELECT num,surname, firstname,ward FROM doctor join ward on (c = w) WHERE num != consultant;
```